# Is there a nice way to check a part of a string is made of letters and the other part is made of numbers in python

Tags: python

I'm making a password checker, and one of the requirements is to check if the password could be a NY license plate (i.e. 3 letters then 4 numbers)

I did it like this:

```
def check_license(password):
    if len(password) == 7:
        if password[0].isalpha() and password[1].isalpha() and password[2].isalpha() and password[3].isdigit() and password[4].isdigit() and password[5].isdigit() and password[6].isdigit():
            print('License: -2')
            score -= 2
```

but I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to format that third line or just a faster way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

def check_license(password):
    return bool(re.match(r'^[A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{4}$', password))
```

Comment: Note that `\w` and `\d` include some characters which are presumably not valid on New York license plates, such as `_` and `୩`.

Comment: Thakn you! This does work for my case since the assignment isn't picky on what characters they are, basically as long as it's 3 characters and 4 numbers. I don't know if it wouldn't work because of chrslgs comment because frankly, I don't really understand how regular expressions work, but ill look into it.

Comment: @EdenBendheim esqew edited their answer after that comment.

Comment: Yes, indeed, my previous comment (made when regexp was ``\w{3}\d{4}``) is no longer pertinent. esqew added the ``^`` and ``$`` needed. And same goes for kaya3's answer, since they also replaced ``\w`` by ``[a-zA-Z]`` and ``\d`` by ``[0-9]`` to strictly match NY plates letters and digits.  Just saying so that future reader of this answer has no doubt that the current answer doesn't have the flaws mentioned. I remove my previous comment to avoid doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Test the two slices of the string like this:

```
def is_license(s):
    return len(s) == 7 and s[:3].isalpha() and s[3:].isdigit()

for test in "abc1234", "ab12345", "ab123cd", "abc123a":
    print(is_license(test)) # True, False, False, False
```

This will include letters and numerals from other alphabets (e.g. `is_license("和bc123٠")` is `True`). To exclude these you could add the condition `s.isascii()`.